# How exactly do you infect the firmware of a hard drive?

Tags: virus, firmware

Now that we are told that infecting firmware has been done in practice, how exactly does this work?

Comment: The novelty is not customizing/infecting firmware per se (look at Travis Goodspeed work for instance). The real deal-breaker here is that they did it using undocumented constructor APIs.

Comment: Reverse engineer the manufacturer's firmware upgrade tool and the firmware itself, and then make your custom (malicious) one.

Comment: There's some information on firmware infections in this article from Schneier and in the comments section: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/01/iratemonk_nsa_e.html

Comment: @Dillinur Could you explain "The real deal-breaker here is that they did it using undocumented constructor APIs" in a bit more detail please?

Comment: I was basically quoting the Kaspersky report on this one : 
"Overall, the plugin uses a lot of undocumented, vendor-specific ATA commands, for the drives mentioned above as well as all the others." See their paper 'EQUATION GROUP: 
QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS'.

Answer (score 3):

There have been a few white papers and conference presentations on this, a quick google search would be a good start. However, this step by step explanation is pretty awesome: http://spritesmods.com/?art=hddhack

Comment: The way I see it, this is a link-only answer. Could you edit the main points from the link into the post?

Answer (score 1):

**It's not about a hard-drive but it can help you to understand practical usage of firmware infecting:**

For example, when a software connects to your webcam, little led on your camera automatically turns on to inform you your webcam is sending data to your computer. Some manufacturers are smart, they connect that led to webcams power line so if camera turns on in anyways, that led turns on. However, some manufacturers do it in a different way. They program the chip on the camera so when data is sending, the chip turns on the led.

If you get the firmware somehow and reverse-engineer it you can remove that rule. To apply that you flash the chip so since your updated firmware doesn't have a rule to turn on the led while sending data, you can spy a webcam without noticing the user.

Comment: That would be a usage of the attack, but doesn't explain how the attack itself works. So I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question.